# I want to buy two TL-WR1043ND wireless router - can they do WDS mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt, wds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure a Router (TL-WR1043ND) to work in WDS mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/301656/how-to-configure-a-router-tl-wr1043nd-to-work-in-wds-mode)

I'm just asking because I don't want to end up having 2 routers, and no WDS network.

I need two because I want to extend the wireless network. One would be the AP the other one as WDS router.

Will they work together or not? (I want to put OpenWrt 10.04 on them.)

I think it they have Atheros AR9132 wireless cards in them.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: It's a technical question. Can they do WDS modE?

Comment: You've done a Web search for "TL-WR1043ND +wds", right?

Comment: WRT160NL is not TL-WR1043ND, so it's not really a duplicate. read the full question before stating such things please.

Comment: You showed a screen shot in the other question of the factory firmware web GUI for that TP-Link TL-WR1043ND specifically allowing you to configure WDS mode, so I'm pretty sure the hardware and factory firmware support it. So is this question really about whether it supports WDS mode *when running OpenWrt*?