# Extend wireless network with 2nd router, then do port forwarding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, wireless-bridge

I have 2 WiFi routers, the main one is also a modem. I'd like to extend the range of the main WiFi with the second router and do port forwarding as I have connected a computer to the 2nd router via a cable. I'd like to know how to configure the 2nd router to do that.

The 2nd router is a TL-WR1042ND (not OpenWrt compatible unfortunately) I have [succeeded in extending the WiFi using WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/301656/how-to-configure-a-router-tl-wr1043nd-to-work-in-wds-mode), but I can't do port forwarding with this method. As I understand WDS being underspecified there are some issues with it.

What happens is that my main router doesn't see the computer I connected to the Ethernet port of the 2nd router and thus is incapable of forwarding data. Connecting the computer to the main router works well. What's interesting is that even though I can't see the device on the main router I can still ping it and SSH to it locally while being connected to the main router.

Is there another method in cloning/extending the WiFi and using port forwarding?

Edit: so what I'm looking for is bridging with port forwarding, is that even possible? Does my 2nd router have to be on the same subnet as the main one?

Comment: Did you turn off DHCP on the second router so the first one can assign IP addresses? If both routers are running DHCP you will have conflicts and communication issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB: yes DHCP is off on the 2nd router just like the instructions I linked to say. I've really searched for the problem and asking questions is my last resort...

Comment: If you have the second ("extender") router set to bridge mode (or "access point" mode) and DHCP is disabled then you shouldn't need to do any configuration for port forwarding on the second router. Everything should be done on the main router as this is the work horse...